# Pipe yuv frames to ffmpeg

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg

I read camera input frames and then do some transformation on them and then I would like to make a video of it. 
At the moment I am writing the raw yuv420 images to sdcard as one big file and then invoking staticly compiled FFMPEG to encode it to mp4 movie.

The problem is because writing 10 images per second results in about 2MB/s of write to SDCARD for an image of 480x320 in yuv420p format. Which is too much for an SDCARD.

So would it be possible to pipe these yuv420 images directly to FFMPEG and how?